# Counterexample to if g ◦ f is surjective, then f and g are surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I want less of an answer and more of an explanation if possible please.

I understand I'm looking for a range of either f and g that is NOT surjective(does not cover all the codomain), but that their composition is.

Comment: Let $f: X \to Y$ be absolutely _any_ map (I require that $X$ is not the empty set). Define a map $g: Y \to \{ 0 \}$ in the only possible way, so $g$ is a constant map $g(y)=0$ for all $y$. Then $g \circ f$ is surjective, $X \xrightarrow{f} Y \xrightarrow{g} \{ 0 \}$. Can you see why? Since $f$ was arbitrary, your result follows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because when $f$ is $A \rightarrow B$ and $g$ is $B \rightarrow C$, the "size" of $B$ may be higher than the one of $A$ and $C$.

For example, you might consider $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^2$ where $f(n) = (n,0)$ and $g : \mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ where $g(n,p) = n$.

Then, $g \circ f = id$ which is bijective hence surjective, but $f$ isn't surjective because there is no $y \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(y) = (0,1)$ which contradicts the definition of a surjection.

However, you can note that I have only given a counterexample to "$f$ is surjective". This is because $g \circ f$ is surjective $\implies g$ is surjective.

For us to prove it, recall that a function $h$ is surjective if and only if every element $x$ of the arrival set has at least an antecedent (that is an element $y$ of the starting set which verifies $h(y) = x$).

Let's consider $x$ an element of the arrival set. Since $g \circ f$ is surjective, we have $y$ that verifies $(g \circ f) (y) = x$, so $g(f(y)) = x$. So $f(y)$ is an antecedent of $x$ by $g$. So $g$ is surjective.

EDIT : A minimal counter example would be $f : \{0\} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ where $f(0) = 1$ and $g : \{0,1\} \rightarrow \{0\}$ where $g(0) = g(1) = 0$. Here, $g \circ f$ is $\{0\} \rightarrow \{0\}$ where $(g \circ f)(0) = 0$ which is surjective, but $f$ isn't because $1 \in \{0,1\}$ but there is no element $x$ in $\{0\}$ such that $f(x) = 1$.

Comment: I understand the concept and why it is possible, but I do not understand how to find an actual solution. I can't even fathom to begin to think of mapping specific ranges to f that show it's not surjective, whereas g is surjective.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it. What do you not understand in my counterexample ? If it is fine, your problem is that you don't know how to build another ?

Comment: I don't know what a dilation is, I don't know what a canonic surjection is, and I'm not sure what you refer to as an antecedent. What you wrote is over my head.

Comment: No problem, I'm editing the post.

Comment: Would this work: f: A -> B , by f(x) = x^(5/3) and g: B -> C, by g(x) = x^3, then g o f (x) = x^5

Comment: I'm afraid it wouldn't, as all these functions are bijective (hence surjective) in their set of definition. If think what stops you from understanding this is that you seem to want to use $\mathbb{R}$. But applications aren't always in $\mathbb{R}$, and in my opinion what you want to see is much easier to understand in other sets ! I'm adding the simplest example I can find.

Answer (score 5):

With questions like this, it is often good to look for the simplest possible example. The one (to me!) that comes to mind is the following.

Let $X = \{0\}$ and let $Y = \{0, 1\}$ (realistically, $Y$ can be any set with more than one element). Define the following functions:
$$
f : X \to Y \qquad \qquad 0 \mapsto 0
$$
and
$$
g : Y \to X \qquad \qquad 0, 1 \mapsto 0
$$
These are both functions, and we note first of all that $f$ is not surjective. However, if we look at the composition $g \circ f$ then it takes $0 \mapsto_f 0 \mapsto_g 0$ and so this composition is just the identity function on $X$, and so is surjective. So we have found a pair of functions $f, g$ such that their composition is surjective, but that *at least one of the two functions* is not.

Again, I think it is helpful to look at the simplest possible examples. Try sets with one or two elements. Draw pictures, if need by (the usual blob-with-arrow version of functions). Play around!